# How do I sample from a black-box model of a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, distributions

I have a function 'P(x)' where we query for any 'x' it gives a probability value. This function 'P' does not have a closed form and the evaluation is costly. Now 'x' is a set of vectors(matrix whose rows) which sum to 1 and each entry in the matrix is greater that 0 and less than or equal to 1. Now this distribution has many peaks and ridges. What method would be appropriate to sample from this 'P'. I want to approximate the distribution by a set of samples. So what would be the appropriate method to use? Which method in MCMC or any would be suitable?

Comment: It is crucial to know what $P(x)$ *means*.  Is it the chance of a random variable $X$ equaling the value $x$, or is it perhaps the chance that $X\le x$? What else is known about the distribution? For instance, do you know that each component of $X$ must lie within given bounds $a \le X \le b$?

Comment: P(x) will give you a pdf value of P(X==x) proportional to a normalizing constant. And 'x' satisfies the conditions specified above. We are searching over a set of simplex.